# Dictionary within a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am querying a database such that it returns something like this:

```
[{"Name": "John", "hair_color": "Brown", "eye_color": "Blue"},
 {"Name": "Sally", "hair_color": "Red", "eye_color": "Green"},
 {"Name": "Bill", "hair_color": NULL, "eye_color": "Blue"}
]
```

How could I loop through that list of dictionaries to output something like this:

```
[{"John": {"Attribute": "hair_color", "Value": "Brown"}},
 {"John": {"Attribute": "eye_color", "Value": "Blue"}},
 {"Sally": {"Attribute": "hair_color", "Value": "Red"}},
 {"Sally": {"Attribute": "eye_color", "Value": "Green"}},
 {"Bill": {"Attribute": "hair_color", "Value": NULL}},
 {"Bill": {"Attribute": "eye_color", "Value": "Blue"}},
]
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: What's the code you've written to solve this and what issues did you face?

Comment: What part are you stuck on? How to loop through a list? How to build up a new list? How to create a new dict out of an old one? Show us where you’re stuck and we can explain that part. Otherwise, all we can do is write you some code you probably won’t be able to understand and maintain, which doesn’t do you much good.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: All: This is my first post, my apologies for missing out on some of the key parts you are asking about.  I'm using Python 3. The code I have written is all over the place but the part that I am stuck on is how to have the name (John, Sally or Bill) be the key to a nested dictionary if I am pulling that name from an existing dictionary.  In other words: How do I get Bill to be the key for {"Bill":{"Attribute": "hair_color", "Value": NULL"}

Comment: Ok. It's a pity that your code is all over the place, but we need some of it to be in _this_ place, preferably in the form of a [mcve]. ;)

Comment: Stop bulling him. He's newbie on this site. His question has input that's easy to copy and expected output. And he asks for easiest solution. What else do you need?

Comment: @Sergei Nobody is bullying the OP. We like people to post some code with questions like this. Partly to demonstrate that they've made an effort to solve it themself, but mostly so we can see how well they understand Python and so we can see exactly where they're stuck. That way we can give them code that they'll understand, and we can correct any misunderstandings revealed by their code.

Comment: Thanks all for support.  The answer's provided worked for me.  Again, apologies for the incorrect format of this post.  Anything posted in the future will follow proper guidelines.

Comment: I do not see any answer, you may want to add one or delete the question completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's more concise and fast code version

```
input_list = [{"Name": "John", "hair_color": "Brown", "eye_color": "Blue"},
              {"Name": "Sally", "hair_color": "Red", "eye_color": "Green"},
              {"Name": "Bill", "hair_color": None, "eye_color": "Blue"}]


output_list = [{person['Name']: {'Attribute': attr_key, 'Value': person[attr_key]}}
               for person in input_list for attr_key in person if attr_key != 'Name']

print(output)
```

Output:

```
[{'John': {'Attribute': 'hair_color', 'Value': 'Brown'}},
 {'John': {'Attribute': 'eye_color', 'Value': 'Blue'}},
 {'Sally': {'Attribute': 'hair_color', 'Value': 'Red'}},
 {'Sally': {'Attribute': 'eye_color', 'Value': 'Green'}},
 {'Bill': {'Attribute': 'hair_color', 'Value': None}},
 {'Bill': {'Attribute': 'eye_color', 'Value': 'Blue'}}]
```

Version with loop

```
# Empty output list
output_list2 = []

# Loop through persons dict
for person in input_list:

    # Save person name
    name = person['Name']

    # Loop through every attr the person
    for attr_key in person:

        # If arribute not Name add new dict to output list 
        if attr_key != 'Name':
            output_list2.append({name: {'Attribute': attr_key, 'Value': person[attr_key]}})   

print(output_list2)
```

Output Version 2:

```
[{'John': {'Attribute': 'hair_color', 'Value': 'Brown'}},
 {'John': {'Attribute': 'eye_color', 'Value': 'Blue'}},
 {'Sally': {'Attribute': 'hair_color', 'Value': 'Red'}},
 {'Sally': {'Attribute': 'eye_color', 'Value': 'Green'}},
 {'Bill': {'Attribute': 'hair_color', 'Value': None}},
 {'Bill': {'Attribute': 'eye_color', 'Value': 'Blue'}}]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> lst = [{"Name": "John", "hair_color": "Brown", "eye_color": "Blue"},
...  {"Name": "Sally", "hair_color": "Red", "eye_color": "Green"},
...  {"Name": "Bill", "hair_color": "NULL", "eye_color": "Blue"}
... ]
>>> 
>>> res = [{d['Name']: {"Attribute": k, "Value": v}} for d in lst for k,v in d.items() if k!='Name']
>>>
>>> pprint(res)
[{'John': {'Attribute': 'hair_color', 'Value': 'Brown'}},
 {'John': {'Attribute': 'eye_color', 'Value': 'Blue'}},
 {'Sally': {'Attribute': 'hair_color', 'Value': 'Red'}},
 {'Sally': {'Attribute': 'eye_color', 'Value': 'Green'}},
 {'Bill': {'Attribute': 'hair_color', 'Value': 'NULL'}},
 {'Bill': {'Attribute': 'eye_color', 'Value': 'Blue'}}]
```

Comment: Your answer would be more valuable if you add some explanation, either as separate text, or in the form of comments. That way, the OP will be better able to understand why your code works, which will help them to learn. Code without explanation isn't so easy to learn from.